# .htaccess redirect URLs with 'trailing slash with post ID' to 'trailing hyphen with post ID' (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I am very beginner to .htaccess. I want to redirect all my Wordpress permalinks as follows:

**example.com/sample-post/12345** to 
**example.com/sample-post-12345**

I changed the permalink structure on Wordpress settings and all URLs works fine.

But I had shared some URLs before on social media in http://example.com/sample-post/12345 format, and now they all are returning "Error 404 - Page not found".

So, it would be great of we can redirect those URLs to the new format. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if the question is unclear. I want to redirect URLs as follows:
example.com/sample-post/12345 to example.com/sample-post-12345

Answer (score 0):

Redirection old URL to new URL by below plugin:

[Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)

Comment: Thanks. Can I bulk redirect all the URLs then? Or should we need to manually add each and every redirection?